# Cloudberry Hybrid Backup

Tags: cloudberry

With the new Hybrid backup option in Cloudberry Server Backup v5.6 is there any way to have different retention policies for the local backups as opposed to the offsite backups?

When running the backup plan creation wizard it only provides for one retention policy for both local/cloud backups and it's no different when you edit the plan after creation?

Is my only option to stick with two separate backup plans one for local and one for cloud, each with their own retention policy?

Comment: Should be available in September-October

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can configure different retention policies in separate plans only.
Thanks for the suggestion! We have added your vote to the feature request.